# EPPlus Excel Pie Chart Style Query

Tags: vb.net, excel, epplus

Good Day All,
I am using EPPlus library to generate pie chart which is coming out in default style. I came across a style which is (Microsoft Excel) Style:7 (for Exploded 3D pie chart) while reviewing the file in Excel and wanted to look for way to apply that style in EPPLus. However I noticed in EPPLus there are about 48 chart styles. I tried a few but none seem to match the style I can get in excel. I am attaching Before (what I am getting by Default by EPPlus) and After (what I want) images of pie chart having styles.

Just for ref I am populating the EPPLUS chart styles in a combobox , so that I can choose one while creating report.:

```
  Dim EPPlusChartStylesDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, eChartStyle)

            EPPlusChartStylesDict.Add(1, eChartStyle.Style1)
            EPPlusChartStylesDict.Add(2, eChartStyle.Style2)
            EPPlusChartStylesDict.Add(3, eChartStyle.Style3)
            'Upto 48
            EPPlusChartStylesDict.Add(48, eChartStyle.Style48)
             EPPlusChartStyleListBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(EPPlusChartStylesDict, Nothing)
            EPPlusChartStyleListBox.DisplayMember = "Value"
            EPPlusChartStyleListBox.ValueMember = "Key"
            EPPlusChartStyleListBox.SelectedIndex = 1
```

Dim EPPlusChartStyle As eChartStyle = DirectCast(EPPlusChartStyleListBox.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of Integer, eChartStyle)).Value

```
        MyTest_Pie.Style = EPPlusChartStyle
```

Can someone please advise.? 
[image: Default Style That I get by EPPlus Export]

[image: Style I want to be..]

Comment: I think I may have found it. Its the Fill Style Color for Chart Area and Plot Area.. will play around and let you know..

Comment: I tried above but will have to add more lines to match each aspect of the chart correctly. Is there any VBA macro that can be executed to change the Chart Style from Excel?

Answer (score 0):

here is my code using epplus to have excel styles,

you have to use
***ePresetChartStyleMultiSeries*** enum,

inside ***SetChartStyle*** method,

from ***StyleManager*** class:

```
myChart.StyleManager.SetChartStyle(OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.Style.ePresetChartStyleMultiSeries.LineChartStyle4);
```

I'm using EPPlus Version=6.0.5.0, in C#.net

Comment: Many thanks Ali Khademi. Its been many years but I have come back to the same code again. I will try this out. What version of EPPLus are you using. I am using the last free available version which I think is 4.5.3.3

Comment: It looks like the StyleManager is not available in the EPPLus version I am using. 
I am getting this message. 

Error BC30456 'StyleManager' is not a member of 'ExcelPieChart'.